# EditText prints a letter twice

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know this is kinda silly and weird question, but its really bugging me. As my post subject says, when I enter a letter in the edit text its printing twice. I tried to find the issue, but couldn't. Here is my code,

**changecode.xml**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/oldcode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/changecodetxt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Enter Old Pass Code"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:password="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/newcode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/oldcode"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Enter New Pass code"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:password="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/renewcode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/newcode"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:hint="Re-Enter New Pass code"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:password="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/savenewcode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:text="Update Code" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/savenewcode"
    android:layout_below="@id/renewcode"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/cc_togglebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textOff="123"
        android:textOn="ABC!@#" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In **MainActivity.java**

```
oldcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oldcode);
                newcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newcode);
                renewcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.renewcode);
                savenewcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savenewcode);
                cc_toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.cc_togglebutton);

                cc_toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        boolean on = cc_toggle.isChecked();
                        if (on) {

                            oldcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                            newcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                            renewcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                        }

                        else {

                            oldcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                            newcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                            renewcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                        }                           
                    }
                });
```

Any kind of help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: What is changecodetxt? I don't see it anywhere else in the XML. I don't see any problem in your code apart from that...

Comment: where u have added print lines plz include print lines also with code

Comment: @psykhi its jus a textview above edittext.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя printing lines in the sense, the letters shown in the edittext which I have entered from the keyboard.

Comment: Well then clean your project, and try with just one editext first, see if you have the problem, if not add the second one, then the third, maybe you'll see where it's going wrong this way :/

Comment: Which EditText is printing twice? Are you testing on real hardware or emulator?